# Plugging in derivatives into an equation

Tags: derivatives

If 
$$B=v\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\right)$$

where

$$v=\frac{r^3}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$$

Can anybody explain me how they get below result:

$$B=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
B
&=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u \\
&=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9}r^3
\left( 
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
\right)
\left(
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
\right)
u \\
&=
\frac{r^3}{\sqrt{2}}
\left( 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
\right)
\left(
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
\right)
u
\end{align}

Comment: got it ! thanks